# Getting All Docker Container's IP Address along with Container ID's and Name's

Tags: docker, containers

Display all the existing container's details with the following output pattern

Container ID - Container Name - IP Address

Answer (score 2):

docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Hostname}} - {{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)